# Styling domain Values in AndroidPlot does not include the first value

Tags: androidplot

I am working on an Android application that requires the use of a Graph, for this purpose I am using AndroidPlot's XYSeries. I am trying to style the graph, everything is fine but the first value of the domain. As you can see in the screen shot below, the style does not apply for all the values
[image: Androidplot screenshot]

This is how I style the values

```
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setTextSize(22);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setTextSize(22);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint()
            .setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong and how to apply the style for all the values?

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem, the first value is called DomainOriginLabelPaint not DomainLabelPaint, in order to style it we need to add

plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint().setTextSize(22);